# How to reload UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I use `UIImagePickerController` to get an image needed in my app.

```
// ...
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
// ...
```

But I found a problem in my process to get an image with `UIImagePickerController`.
When `UIImagePickerController` object's view is on device screen, user can make my app go to background and take a picture with other apps. User backs to my app then, my app still shows `UIImagePickerController` object's view. But the contents in Photo library is not changed unless user reopen `UIImagePickerController`.
I need to reload `UIImagePickerController` object's view. How to do it?
This question is about reloading `UIImagePickerController`, not app foreground notification.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the notification you can destroy and recreate the picker. This will refresh the images available but will lose any current selection / scroll position. As such, it probably isn't a good idea to always reload (you can use the assets library to check if the image count changed).